# Can I get pages from the WP-PostRatings and WP-PostVevs plugins using get_posts()?

Tags: wordpress

I use WP-PostRatings WP-PostViews plugins and was able to display pages using functions

```
<?php if (function_exists('get_highest_rated')): ?>
   <ul><?php get_lowest_rated(); ?></ul>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if (function_exists('get_most_viewed')): ?>
   <ul><?php get_most_viewed(); ?></ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

but they are displayed as plain text and I cannot edit them, add a thumbnail of the post and do other things is it possible to not display them as if using get_posts() like this

```
<?php 
global $post;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'orderby' => 'comment_count',
    'order'=> 'ASC'
);
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ){ setup_postdata($post);?>
  <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
  <?php } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

but only for rating and views